# submenu click event not working/firing

Tags: jquery

the click code for the main menu works the class changes and all but not on submenu ...it doesn't fire the alert command when submenu item like food or shoes is clicked...in fact hover works perfect for submenu but not the active

**HTML**

```
<aside>
    <div class=sidebar>
        <ul class=nav>
            <li class="home active" data-class="page_home">HOME</li>
            <li class="products" data-class="page_products">BYE</li>
            <li class="ART" data-class="page_art">ART</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</aside>
<article>
    <div class="page_home show">
        <div class="myhome">
             <h1>Home</h1>

            <p>this is the index page</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="page_products">
        <ul class="productcat">
            <li class="food">FOOD</li>
            <li class="shoes">SHOES</li>
            <li class="cloths">CLOTHS</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="page_art">
        <div class="myart">
             <h1>ART</h1>

            <p>this is art page</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

**JS**

```
$(".page_products ul.productcat li").on('click', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        // Class of the one to be shown
        subclazz = $this.data("class");
    alert("button clicked");

    $this.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
}

$("ul.nav li").on('click', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        // Class of the one to be shown
        clazz = $this.data("class");

    $this.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    $('article > div').removeClass('show');
    $('.' + clazz).addClass('show');

});
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    width:1020px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:absolute;
}
aside {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    width:20%;
}
article {
    float:right;
    display:block;
    margin-top:0;
    width:75%;
}
.page_home, .page_products, .page_art{
    visibility:hidden;
}
.show {
    visibility: visible;
}
.sidebar {
    margin-left:10px;
}
.nav {
    display:block;
    margin-top:60px;
    list-style-type:none;
}
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    color:#000;
}
.nav > li {
    background: #666 no-repeat;
    width:150px;
    height:65px;
    color:#000;
}
.nav >li:hover {
    background:#06F no-repeat;
}
.nav > li.active {
    background:#06F no-repeat;
}


.productcat > li {
    background: #666 no-repeat;
    width:150px;
    height:65px;
    color:#fff;   
    display:inline; 
    padding:10px;
}


.productcat>li:hover {
background:#06F no-repeat;

}

.productcat > li.active {
background:#06F no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: The hover works because it isn't being scripted, unlike the `click` event... If I were to guess, I would say you are targeting the element wrong, probably...

Comment: What happens if you target it with `$("ul.productcat li")` instead of `$(".page_products ul.productcat li")`?

Comment: @dimple. What does not work

Comment: @sushant...plz can u help with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885748/subpage-display-based-on-submenu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try  using

```
$(".page_products ul.productcat li").on('click', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
        // Class of the one to be shown
        subclazz = $this.attr("class");
        alert("button clicked");

    $this.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
}
```

i changed

```
subclazz = $this.data("class");
```

to

```
subclazz = $this.attr("class");
```

**and**

```
var $this = $(this),
```

to

```
var $this = $(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 issues with your code..

You forgot the closing braces for the first event handler

```
$(".page_products ul.productcat li").on('click', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        // Class of the one to be shown
        subclazz = $this.data("class");
    alert("button clicked");

    $this.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
 ^---- Missing closing braces here
```

Second, you are using `data` method to access a custom method

```
  subclazz = $this.data("class");
```

But the HTML you are working with is in this form

```
<li class="food">FOOD</li>
```

So if you wanted your `data` method to work, your HTMl structure is supposed to be

```
  <li data-class="food">FOOD</li>
```

Also you are not using this variable anywhere in your code which is not necessary. And I am surprised you say your 2nd event handler works after your syntax error.

Hover works here in this case as the style is  applied using CSS and not javascript, and a error in javascript does not have any effect when styles are applied.

You can always check the errors in js by inspecting the console in the developer tools.

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/xug2z/6/)**

Comment: Stop approving the crap in the edit queue! The tag-wiki edits you're blindly approving are A) very bad and B) copied directly from the first Google result, which is *expressly* forbidden.

Comment: @meagar.. Sorry abt it.. I ll be more careful the next time I do it !

Comment: hey sushant if u can plz help with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885748/subpage-display-based-on-submenu